# Wifi causing full system lockup

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

Not sure if this is the best place to post this, but any help with this would be appreciated. I'm having issues with running Ubuntu on my Laptop. System configuration is:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit)
- Generic HP Notebook (Core i3-6006U with a 120 GB SSD)
- Realtek rtl8723be wireless adapter (this is probably relevant)

The issue I am having is that my computer is completely freezing periodically (every couple of hours or so), it randomly hangs up and everything becomes unresponsive (mouse and keyboard inputs also become unresponsive) and the only way to recover is to 'raise elephants'  and completely reboot the computer.

I've deduced the issue has to do with the Wifi adapter (or perhaps the driver for it) by looking at the syslog and looking at the last log messages before the crash happens. Here's the last few messages before I force reboot:

```
Apr 16 00:24:21 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356260.0280] connectivity: (wlo1) timed out
Apr 16 00:24:22 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356260.4204] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 16 00:24:23 khurram-HP-Notebook dbus-daemon[741]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=767 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Apr 16 00:24:24 khurram-HP-Notebook whoopsie[1355]: [00:24:22] offline
Apr 16 00:24:31 khurram-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 16 00:24:43 khurram-HP-Notebook whoopsie[1355]: [00:24:42] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 16 00:28:24 khurram-HP-Notebook org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1547]: [10461:10849:0416/002819.804731:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(243)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
Apr 16 00:28:31 khurram-HP-Notebook kernel: [27588.502173] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
Apr 16 00:28:31 khurram-HP-Notebook kernel: [27588.502186] wlo1: Connection to AP 48:57:02:1c:f1:90 lost
Apr 16 00:28:39 khurram-HP-Notebook wpa_supplicant[754]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=48:57:02:1c:f1:90 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Apr 16 00:28:40 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <warn>  [1555356520.1564] sup-iface[0x5561743faa40,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Apr 16 00:28:41 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356521.3787] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> scanning
Apr 16 00:28:42 khurram-HP-Notebook wpa_supplicant[754]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 16 00:28:43 khurram-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 16 00:28:44 khurram-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 16 00:28:48 khurram-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 16 00:29:42 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356574.2820] connectivity: (wlo1) timed out
Apr 16 00:29:51 khurram-HP-Notebook wpa_supplicant[754]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 48:57:02:1c:f1:90 (SSID='Khuram-SF' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 16 00:29:53 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356592.8511] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr 16 00:29:55 khurram-HP-Notebook NetworkManager[767]: <info>  [1555356594.8499] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr 16 00:31:46 khurram-HP-Notebook wpa_supplicant[754]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 48:57:02:1c:f1:90 (SSID='Khuram-SF' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 16 00:33:25 khurram-HP-Notebook /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1387]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 tap: offset negative (-1897ms)
Apr 16 00:33:34 khurram-HP-Notebook kernel: [27891.449923] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
```

The system lockup started around the time 00:31:46 where the message related to trying to authenticate shows up. I believe the last two messages are related to the input controller dying and me entering magic sysreq commands. The next message in the log is the microcode that shows up on bootup.

I've also confirmed that the wifi controller is *indeed* the issue. Since disabling it and connecting via a wired ethernet connection, gets rid of all the issues.

Here's the hardware information for the wireless controller:

```
  *-network        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 3c:52:82:b5:89:5d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.18.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 3c:95:09:a1:f2:ed
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
```

And the result of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I'm unsure of what else to look at. Googling the issue doesn't result in much - apparently this wireless adapter had some issues with signal strength at one point, and those are the only results I get. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I'm wondering if it could be a combination of gdm3 and your wifi as I did have gdm3 locking up on be before. Can you switch to lightdm temporarily to see if this problem still persist? Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to switch to lightdm.

Comment: lightdm wasn't installed by default. Just installed it and switched over to it. I've connected via Wifi again but since the issue is sporadic, I probably wont know if it fixed anything right away.

Comment: @BernardWei Lightdm made significant performance improvements but didn't result in less crashes. Just experienced another crash while trying to set up my synaptics touchpad driver to work with Lightdm in a similar manner to before. Currently switching back to gdm3 since I have it configured to my liking.